# How do I query two tables for a filtered result in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with buildings(8052monticello) and a separate table with offices(individualspecs), Upon clicking on a respective building link in the buildings page I send the building id to through a get request to the handling page unit_specs.php, however unit_specs is showing me all the units in the table, however I only want unit_specs.php to display the units corresponding to its respective building. How can I fix this?

```
 $querystats='SELECT individualspecs.Space, individualspecs.Size, 
 individualspecs.Price, individualspecs.Id';
 $querystats.= ' FROM individualspecs'; 
 $querystats.= ' INNER JOIN 8052monticello ON 
 individualspecs.fk_Id=8052monticello.id';

if ($r = mysqli_query($connection, $querystats)) { // Run the query.
// Retrieve and print every record:
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {

if ($row['Price']){

    print "<p><h3> Unit # {$row['Space']}</h3>  
    {$row['Size']} Sq Feet<br>
    {$row['Price']} Monthly rent<br>
    <a href=\"edit_UNIT.php?Id={$row['Id']}\">Edit</a>
    <a href=\"delete_UNIT.php?Id={$row['Id']}\">Delete</a>
    </p><hr>\n";
}
}
}
```

[units table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8bRv.jpg)

[buildings table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueQuc.jpg)

here is the full code:

```
 <!doctype html>

 <html lang="en">

 <head>
 <style>
.container{
    padding: 1em;
}

</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384- 
Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>View the units @ </title>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<h1>Units</h1><hr>

<?php // Script 12.6 - view_BUILDINGS.php


$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password', 
'BUILDINGS');




// Define the query but only for info:


$querystats='SELECT individualspecs.Space, individualspecs.Size, 
individualspecs.Price, individualspecs.Id';
$querystats.= ' FROM individualspecs'; 
$querystats.= ' WHERE individualspecs.fk_building= 8052monticello.UNIT';

if ($r = mysqli_query($connection, $querystats)) { // Run the query.
// Retrieve and print every record:
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {

if ($row['Price']){

    print "<p><h3> Unit # {$row['Space']}</h3>  
    {$row['Size']} Sq Feet<br>
    {$row['Price']} Monthly rent<br>
    <a href=\"edit_UNIT.php?Id={$row['Id']}\">Edit</a>
    <a href=\"delete_UNIT.php?Id={$row['Id']}\">Delete</a>
    </p><hr>\n";
}
}
} 


//end of get image query
else { // Query didn't run.

print '<p style="color: red;">Could not retrieve the data because:<br>' . 
mysqli_error($connection) . '.</p><p>The query being run was: ' . 
$querystats . '</p>';

} // End of query IF.



mysqli_close($connection); // Close the connection.



?>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes individualspecs.fk_Id is foreign key on individualspecs table and its the same as 8052monticello.id (primary key on 8052monticello table). Unfortunately I tried your solution it did not work. I ran the following query:   $querystats='SELECT individualspecs.Space, individualspecs.Size, individualspecs.Price, individualspecs.Id';
  $querystats.= ' FROM individualspecs'; 
  $querystats.= ' WHERE individualspecs.fk_Id= 8052monticello.id'; and I recieved this error: Unknown column '8052monticello.id' in 'where clause'.

Comment: I tried to run this with a where clause as you had suggested, I also tried to run it comparing the $_GET[id] as that is what is being passed in the url. I did not succeed with either of the methods you suggested. can you please provide more clarification.

Comment: I have attached screenshots of the respective tables to the original post for clarification. I tried to run 'SELECT individualspecs.Space, individualspecs.Size, individualspecs.Price, individualspecs.Id FROM individualspecs WHERE individualspecs.fk_Id= 8052monticello.id' since I did not understand your answer can you please provide the correct query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things here...

1. You aren't using anything from `8052monticello` so there's no reason to *join* it in
2. Assuming your request looks something like `/unit_specs.php?id=123`, you need to compare `individualspecs.fk_Id` (your building ID) with `$_GET['id']`. The best way to do so is use a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and bind the parameter.

For example

```
$buildingId = $_GET['id'] ?? null; // PHP 7 syntax, use "$buildingId = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : null;" for older versions
$stmt = $connection->prepare(
        'SELECT Space, Size, Price, Id FROM individualspecs WHERE Price > 0 AND fk_Id = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $buildingId); // bind the first parameter as an integer
$stmt->execute();
// I just find bind_result() easier to work with, YMMV
$stmt->bind_result($space, $size, $price, $id); 
// PHP's alternative syntax makes for better readability IMO
while ($stmt->fetch()) : ?>
  <p>
    <h3> Unit # <?= $space ?></h3> <!-- FYI: H3 should not be in a P tag -->
    <?= $size ?> Sq Feet<br>
    <?= $price ?> Monthly rent<br>
    <a href="edit_UNIT.php?Id=<?= $id ?>">Edit</a>
    <a href="delete_UNIT.php?Id=<?= $id ?>">Delete</a> <!-- deleting via a GET request is a bad idea -->
  </p>
  <hr>
<?php endwhile;
```

---

Useful links:

- [PHP: Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)
- [Alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)
- [`mysqli_prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.prepare.php)
- [`mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`](http://php.net/manual/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)
- [`mysqli_stmt_execute()`](http://php.net/manual/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)
- [`mysqli_stmt_bind_result()`](http://php.net/manual/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)
- [`mysqli_stmt_fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php)

Comment: I apologize, I couldn't get the solutions to work, I do not know the object oriented style. I appreciate your help though. here is the github If you have time to take a look and help me. I do not understand the binding priniciples you were discussing. But I do see its a problem constructing a query that relies on two tables without using it.  https://github.com/KravMaguy/Basic-Listing-App

Comment: @greykrav _"I do not know the object oriented style"_ I recommend you learn it but if you want, you can continue using the procedural functions `mysqli_prepare()`, `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`, etc. _"I do not understand the binding priniciples you were discussing"_ that's why I provided a link. Here it is again ~ http://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Im reading the documentation you shared but finding it difficult to make a correlation, im unsure which example to follow, I did copy and paste your code into my example but kept getting an unexpected end of file I could not solve. Is there a way to query the two tables so I dont have to use it? or just restructure the tables so i can achieve this result. On the first page should be a list of buildings. And when a user clicks on a building he advances to the next page which shows all the units belonging to that building.

Comment: @greykrav _"unexpected end of file"_ sounds like you've got a typo somewhere. I've updated my answer as I can guess where that might be

Comment: I went over your code a few times, the links you sent me are indeed helpful, but I still do not have the solution. when I copied and pasted your code over my own I am receiving error messages calls to undefined function fetch.. I attached the FULL code im using to my original post. I wish I had the answer as ive been working on this for the past few days.

Comment: @greykrav whoops, looks like a typo in my code. Will fix it. Change `$stmt-fetch()` to `$stmt->fetch()`

Comment: Negative phil, still not working. can you please copy and paste your solution into my code, once it works I will be sure to go over it line by line until I fully understand everything. I also tried to pm you but I dont have enough respect points..did you get a chance to see the full code I posted to the original thread?

Comment: @greykrav your two examples don't match. One has `individualspecs.fk_Id` / `8052monticello.id` and the other has `individualspecs.fk_building` / `8052monticello.UNIT`. So which is correct? The first matches your DB table screenshots. Anyway, here's what you asked for ~ https://pastebin.com/a6SumCXg

Comment: It is working. Now i will go over everything in detail so I can understand the mistakes I was making. Thank you for taking the time to explain it to me and providing the links. Much appreciated. Happy holidays.